# Updating total price in java script

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i have a simple questions , I'm not the greatest in JavaScript but i was wondering how i can update a total number. I have button were i can add items to cart and that updates fine, so i used the same method to try and update the total price but it only works once and then it wont add any more.

So When i first add the item the cart updates +1 and the price goes to 565

Second time i update the cart goes to +2 which is perfect but the price stays at 565 when it should go to 1130.

Any help on this matter would be great

HTML:

```
<a class="shopping-cart" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="cart-badge">0</span></a>
<p class="cartPrice">0.00 kr</p><input id="search-submit" type="submit">
```

Javascript:

```
var currentItems = 0;
var cartPrice = 565.00;
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
           currentItems++;
           cartPrice + cartPrice;
           $(".cart-badge").text(currentItems);
           $(".cartPrice").text(cartPrice);
       });
});
```

So you can see the quantity updates perfectly but the total price only works once

Thanks again

Edit:

I just tried `cartPrice += cartPrice`;  but it doubled it every time

Comment: `cartPrice += cartPrice;` You have not assigned the value to the current value.

Comment: @Learnonhardway Wrong. It keep double the value. Where as it should be `currentItems  * cartPrice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious issue with your code is the line:

```
cartPrice + cartPrice;
```

This doesn't do anything because you are not assigning the result. You would have to do either of the following instead:

```
cartPrice += cartPrice;
cartPrice = cartPrice + cartPrice;
```

However, that will cause you issues as you will end up doubling the price each time.

The solution is that you should not change `cartPrice` at all, otherwise you have no way to know the cost of each item for subsequent calculations.

Instead create a local variable and calculate it based on number of items * item cost. Something like this:

```
var currentItems = 0;
var cartPrice = 565.00;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
       currentItems++;
       var totalPrice = currentItems * cartPrice;
       $(".cart-badge").text(currentItems);
       $(".cartPrice").text(totalPrice);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you very much , Need to keep learning some more js!

Comment: Just a quick question if i wanted to keep "kr" at the end of the string how could i do this? as it updates the number perfectly but deletes the "kr" Thank you again , helped me a lot xx

Comment: like this `$(".cartPrice").text(totalPrice + " kr")`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Thanks very much , just did it is well :)

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are immutable. You have to keep overriding with new values.

```
cartPrice + cartPrice;
```

That is wrong in 2 ways. It wont update as you are not reassigning and then it keeps double the cart price.

It should be

```
cartPrice = currentItems  * cartPrice;
```

Comment: But that doubles it every time, i just need it to add +565 every time as thats the price of the object , so it should go first add 565, second add 1130 , third add 1695 etc

Comment: @RonTheOld Well `cartPrice = currentItems  * cartPrice;` doubling the price ? No it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when press **.add-to-cart** it will called and do the increment in **cartPrice** but after second time it will reinitialize the same things that's why it will not increment second time.

> var currentItems = 0;
>
> var cartPrice = 565.00;
>
> var i=0;
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
>    $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
>    
>        currentItems++;
>        if(i == 1)
>        {
>        var Price = $(".cartPrice").text();
>        cartPrice=Number(Price) + 565 ;
>        $(".cartPrice").text(cartPrice);
>        $(".cart-badge").text(currentItems);           
>        }
>        else
>        {
>         cartPrice + cartPrice;
>         $(".cart-badge").text(currentItems);
>         $(".cartPrice").text(cartPrice);
>         i=1;
>        }
>        
>    }); });
> ```

on first time take your default value
and then
get your value from

**$(".cartPrice").text();**

it's worked.